# One term of (2π+5)^n = 288000π^8, what's n?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Without using calculator what's the value of n?

Using binomial expansion I get:

<sup>n</sup>C<sub>p</sub> * 2<sup>n-p</sup> * π<sup>n-p</sup> * 5<sup>p</sup> = 288000π<sup>8</sup>

Easily I know that n-p=8, by the π's power

Then the power of 2 is also 8, so I can divide both sides

<sup>n</sup>C<sub>p</sub> * 5<sup>p</sup> = 1125

Well I know that

- n-p=8
- n-8=p
- n=p+8

And with "pascal triangle's" rule(<sup>n</sup>C<sub>p</sub> = <sup>n</sup>C<sub>n-p</sub>)

<sup>n</sup>C<sub>8</sub> * 5<sup>p</sup> = 1125

<sup>n</sup>C<sub>8</sub> * 5<sup>n-8</sup> = 1125

Well there are definitively many ways to  equate this, but how can I get the value of n without calculator or guessing(Trial and error)?

Or is there any other approach?

The answer is n=10 and p=2...

Sorry for no LaTeX(I don't know how to work with it

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The initial use of binomial theorem doesn't look quite right -- you'd want $\pi^p$ instead of $\pi^{(n-p) * p}$. So either $p = 8$ or $n-p = 8$ and you would have $2^p$ instead of $2^{n-p}$.

Comment: It was my bad sorry, corrected it

Answer (score 3):

The term of degree $8$ in the expansion of $(x+a)^n$ is
$$
\binom{n}{8}a^{n-8}x^8
$$
so you want to solve
$$
\binom{n}{8}5^{n-8}2^8=288000=2^83^25^3
$$
hence
$$
\binom{n}{8}5^{n-11}=9
$$
We can exclude $n>11$, because the right hand side is not divisible by $5$.

Therefore you just have to check $n=8,9,10,11$:
\begin{align}
\binom{8}{8}&=1 \\
\binom{9}{8}&=\binom{9}{1}=9 \\
\binom{10}{8}&=\binom{10}{2}=\cdots\\
\binom{11}{8}&=\binom{11}{3}=\cdots
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

> ${n\choose 8} * 5^{n-8} = 1125$

But $1125 = 9*5^3$ so $5^{n-8}|5^3$ and $8\le n \le 11$

And $5^{n-11}{n\choose 8} = 9$.

$9\not \mid 5$ so either $n-11=0$ or $5^{11-n}|{n\choose 8}$.

Now as $8\le n\le 11$ and ${n\choose 8}=\frac {9*..n}{(n-8)!}$ then $11 - n$ is at most $1$.

So $n = 10$ or $11$. Now as no prime but $3,5$ divide $\frac {9*..*n}{(n-8)!}$ we can not have $n = 11$ so

so $n =10$.